# Music similar to the symphonic part of "Time I" by Wintersun

Tags: genre, metal

I've spent several days looking for music that sounds like "[Time I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oKFT9D8GVk)" by the metal band Wintersun before the metal happens, to no avail. I can't seem to find the right thing to google, and looking up "music that sounds like the beginning of Time I by Wintersun" or anything of that sort doesn't yield good results either. "Ambient symphonic music" was the best thing I could think of to look up, but industrial neofolk and philip glass were basically all I was getting.

Comment: What did you mean exactly when you say: `music that sounds like (your sample theme song)` ? Please, try expand your question with more details, details that anyone can use for help you, Meanwhile, see my answer.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this "industrial neofolk" genre.

Comment: Not necessarily close to the sample, but you might want to look up [Apocalyptica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-B8k0n_3cs) for an orchestral take on the metal songbook.

Answer (score 2):

Making a quick search in [findmymusicbylyrics.com](http://findmusicbylyrics.com), you can get some results which differ to *Wintersun (the metal band that you quoted in your question)*,

Hence, there may be another music with the same of similar composition, genre, etc.

Enter to the link website and type:

> *[wintersun time I](http://findmusicbylyrics.com/search.php?cx=partner-pub-1936238606905173%3A1893984547&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=wintersun%20time%20I&sa=Search)*

Answer (score 1):

I can't watch the video here, but i'm assuming you've sent [this music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTyDoDZEhAw&list=PLoJZNEC9yAUoqtzH0uarAE4RkE5nPs4Ya).

It's definitely the style of epic medieval soundtracks. It draws inspiration from medieval music but i would not describe it as folk. You're up to find what you're looking for in the soundtrack area, especially for movies, but eventually for games. Shadow of the Colossu's OST deserves your attention. Also try The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim. Oh, and i couldn't not mention Lord of the Rings.

Be aware though that soundtracks are long and heterogenous, so it will take you some time to find the right tracks.

While some cinematic stuff can focus on a more modern approach, on this one you can feel a bit more of medieval stuff (while, of course, it's still only an 'flavor')

A lot of metal bands draws from medieval stuff folk songs, like celtic/irish/nordic/etc and mix with symphonic and cinematic styles, so you can also take a bet on other similar metal bands. In this place i can't help you much, but it's a direction.

Also there are some people actually making 'stand-alone albums' inspired by that kind of music, but i don't know many names.

[Scottish Moors Album](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=239fNGLXYWs)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend some of the instrumental ballads by band "Eluveitie" such as the songs "Isara", "Liminal passage" & "Anagantios"

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to call this "epic new age" music.  I did a search for that on YouTube, and this is the first thing that came up:

[Beyond Heaven's River - Phil Thorton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz7kJDEsAZk)

To my ear, at least, it's in the same general ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

A few songs that might be interesting -

- Eluveitie - Isara
- Eluveitie - The Liminal Passage
- Eluveitie - Inis Mona (Instrumental)
- Ash - Mosaique
- Zariya - AR Rahman
- Wintersun - When Time Fades Away
- Kamelot- A Sailorman's Hymn
- Snuff - Slipknot
- Apocalyptica- Faraway 
  An exhaustive discussion could be found at https://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/18.231245-Unexpectedly-good-slow-songs-from-heavy-bands